# C++ custom-written strncpy without padding all characters to null is it safe?

Tags: c++, string, std, strncpy, c-standard-library

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Packet {
    int a;
    char b[17];
    int c;
};

// char* dest has form char dest[n], src has length <= n and is null-terminated
// After the function, dest should satisfy:
// - If strlen(src)==n, dest is not null terminated
// - If strlen(src) < n, dest[n-1] = dest[strlen(src)] = '\0'
static void strncpy_faster(char* dest, const char* src, size_t n) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      dest[i] = src[i];
      if (src[i] == '\0')
        break;
    }
    //while (i < n) {dest[i] = '\0'; i++;} // C standard strncpy do this
    if (i < n)
      dest[n - 1] = '\0';
 }
 
 string charArrayToString(const char* a, size_t n) {
    size_t len = 0;
    while (len < n && a[len]!='\0') len++;
    return std::string(a, a+len);
 }

int main()
{
    string s = "12341234123412345";
    Packet packet;
    
    strncpy_faster(packet.b, s.c_str(), 17);
    cout << charArrayToString(packet.b, sizeof(packet.b)) << "\n";
    
    s = "12345";
    strncpy_faster(packet.b, s.c_str(), 17);
    cout << charArrayToString(packet.b, sizeof(packet.b));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm dealing with struct that have fixed-size char arrays. Let's say I really, really want to keep struct size small (or I need to send them over network), so `std::string` is not used in my struct (it cost 32 bytes, while I have multiple small char arrays with size 4-20). I have 2 problems with strncpy:

- `strncpy` 2 char array with same length will emit warning about "potentially not having null-terminated character", which is intended, but I don't need that warning.
- `strncpy` pad ALL leftover characters (from `dest[strlen(src) -> n-1]`) with `'\0'`. This is a waste of processing in my program.

So, my `strncpy_faster` only assign up to 2 positions to '\0': the last element of the array, and the position of `strlen(src)`. Since `std::string()` requires a null-terminated char array (NTCA), I use `charArrayToString()` to convert non-NTCA to string.

Is this version of `strncpy` safe? Are there any C/C++ functions that requires `strncpy` to fill all leftover bytes with `'\0'`, or do they only need a null terminator? I don't know why the standard requires `strncpy` to zero-out remaining bytes.

Comment: Note that C/C++ is not a language. C and C++ are two different languages. Your code is clearly C++ and not C so I've removed the C tag.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't intend to ask about std::string at first. I've edited the question title

Comment: What does the standard tell you about `strncpy()`? Does it promise that all leftover characters are set to `'\0'`?

Comment: @thebusybee [yes](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.4) (and I have no idea why).

Comment: A single null terminator is all that is required. But worrying about zeroing out a few bytes as "a waste of processing" is seriously premature optimisation. All these library functions are heavily optimised and have fast paths that will almost certainly outperform your for loop above. And there are plenty of corner cases that you need to verify your function has before it could really be considered safe. Just use `strncpy` - and you probably want to make your struct packed if it's really going over the wire.

Comment: Also FYI `std::string` is only 24 bytes in LLVM - the short string optimisation (SSO) is pretty clever - https://joellaity.com/2020/01/31/string.html

Comment: @gavinb I'm aware that packed will be included when there's networking. Also, sizeof(string) in my compiler (gcc) gives 32 bytes; also my big problem is strnpy gives warning and I don't want to disable it with #pragma everywhere. Finally, can you list some corner cases?

Comment: Well, if the standard says so, your solution is not safe, as any user might rely on that. If you want just a faster version for your specific use case, you know whether it's safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this version of strncpy safe?

Yes.

It's as safe as `strncpy` is. So.... not safe.

> Are there any C/C++ functions that requires strncpy to fill all leftover bytes with '\0', or do they only need a null terminator?

No function require it.

Notes from Linux man-pages `man strcpy`:

> NOTES
>
> Some  programmers  consider strncpy() to be inefficient and error
> prone.  If the programmer knows (i.e., includes code to test!)    that
> the size of dest is greater than the length of src, then strcpy() can
> be used.
>
> One valid (and intended) use of strncpy() is to copy a C string to
> a fixed-length buffer while ensuring both that the buffer  is    not
> overflowed and that unused bytes in the destination buffer are zeroed
> out (perhaps to prevent information leaks if the buffer is to be
> written to media or transmitted to another process via an interprocess
> communication technique).

Consider using (and/or implementing) `strlcpy`. Remember about [first rule of optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub).